# moving ball app with acceleration sensor does not look smooth and continuous

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to learn making games with android using sensors. What I'm trying to do is to make a ball moving in the screen using acceleration sensor. Actually, I did some part of it. The ball moves in the screen when acceleration of x and y changes. But my problem is that it does not look smooth. It looks like the ball is not drawn on the screen in continuous paths. I use the `SurfaceView` class for this app and I made the drawing on different thread than the main thread. 
Below part of code is from my `MainActivity` class and it is the sensor related part:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long delta_t = actualTime - lastUpdate;

            lastUpdate = actualTime;

            ax = event.values[0];
            ay = event.values[1];

            if (ax > 0) {
                isleft = true;
                delta_x = (float) (0.005 * ax * delta_t * delta_t);

            }
            if (ax < 0) {
                isleft = false;
                delta_x = (float) (-0.005 * ax * delta_t * delta_t);

            }
            if (ay > 0) {
                isdown = true;
                delta_y = (float) (0.005 * ay * delta_t * delta_t);

            }
            if (ay < 0) {
                isdown = false;
                delta_y = (float) (-0.005 * ay * delta_t * delta_t);

            }

            getBallPos();
        }

    }

    private void getBallPos() {
        delta_x /= 10000;
        delta_y /= 10000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            if (isleft)
                ballview.setX_loc(ballview.getX_loc() - delta_x);

            if (!isleft)
                ballview.setX_loc(ballview.getX_loc() + delta_x);

            if (isdown)
                ballview.setY_loc(ballview.getY_loc() + delta_y);

            if (!isdown)
                ballview.setY_loc(ballview.getY_loc() - delta_y);
        }

    }
```

Below part of code is from my `BallGame` class that extends `SurfaceView` and I do the drawings on a different thread:

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (isItOk) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);
                // canvas.drawLine(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY,
                // paint);
                checkBoundaries();
                canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x_loc, y_loc, null);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            }
        }

        private void checkBoundaries() {

            if (x_loc > canvas.getWidth() - ballWidth) {
                x_loc = canvas.getWidth() - ballWidth;

            }
            if (y_loc > canvas.getHeight() - ballHeight) {
                y_loc = canvas.getHeight() - ballHeight;

            }
            if (x_loc < 0) {
                x_loc = 0;

            }
            if (y_loc < 0) {
                y_loc = 0;

            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are two problems:

First is, that you are updating the ball position in `onSensorChanged` method. This method is called by the system and it is not guaranteed that the calling is done in constant frequency. In this case is ball movement depended on these calls. I think the better way would be to store the last `ax` and `ay` as a variables which would be accessible by both `onSensorChanged` method for writing values and drawing thread for reading. Then you can compute ball position in drawing thread, which could redraw canvas with constant frequency.

This brings us to the second problem which is drawing thread while loop. It is not controlled how often is the canvas redrawn. It is big load for system. Better way is to choose the refresh rate (for example 50 frames per second) and update the drawing at this frequency. It could be done at the end of the while loop, where `Thread.sleep()` function can be called. You can measure when the frame drawing started `long frameStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()` at the start of the while loop and then call at the end of the while loop:

```
long sleepTime = refreshInterval-(System.currentTimeMillis()-frameStartTime );
if (sleepTime > 0) {
    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
}
```

(for 50 fps is refreshInterval = 1000/50 = 20 ms).

This calling sleeps the thread for the time of frame refresh interval minus time which was used to draw the ball. When you select adequate refresh rate system load will be lower and will have more time for redrawing.